# How to implement nested tabs in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, nav-pills

I am working on a project where the web app has 6 tabs including the home screen which I have developed using the *ng-show* with each tab having *ng-click="setTab(1)"*

For one of these tabs, I have other four tabs in it. I tried using the *Bootstrap Tabs and Pills* but it didn't workout.

Can anyone help me with implementing the nested tabs in AngularJS.

Comment: share some code to debug.

Comment: I have shared the code for the question I asked
https://jsfiddle.net/b3Lrk3o7/
My javascript file contains script for the entire web app hence it would not be advisable to share the entire file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to implement what the question mentioned using the same method for the tabs. 
For the tabs inside a particular tab, I created the same methods/functions using *ng-show*, *ng-click* and *ng-class* for setting the tabs with different names.